# Access multiple return values (a, b, c) from solidity function in web3js

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have a function that returns multiple values. I wish to access these from Web3js.

```
function testReturnBet(uint index) constant returns (address player, 
                                                     uint tokensPlaced, 
                                                     uint8[4] numbers,
                                                     uint ratioIndex,
                                                     uint timestamp,
                                                     uint rollIndex,
                                                     uint winAmount) {
        bet outBet = bets[index];
        return (outBet.player,
                outBet.tokensPlaced, 
                outBet.numbers, 
                outBet.ratioIndex, 
                outBet.timestamp, 
                outBet.rollIndex, 
                outBet.winAmount);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get an array of return values with 7 values (0-6). The third one should be an array with 4 values.

In the Truffle style, it would look something like:

```
contract.testReturnBet(index).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response); // should be an array
});
```

Comment: So the return value is simply an array of all the return values in order. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

This question is the same as [this one on Ethereum.SE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66174/how-to-access-in-javascript-multiple-return-values-returned-from-a-solidity-func/104083#104083).

As suggested there as well, follow this blog for full details: https://blockheroes.dev/js-read-multiple-returned-values-solidity/

The solution for you should be the following:

```
const result = await contractInstance.yourFunction(param);
const {0: variable_1, 1: variable_2} = result;
```

Comment: Ioana Roceanu, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)